# Parameter 'values' is not executed correctly

Tags: mysql

**Code 1**

```
connection.query(SELECT * FROM shop_product WHERE productid in(1,2,3,4,5)` ,(error, results, fields)=> {...})
// results length is 5
```

**Code 2**

```
connection.query(SELECT * FROM shop_product WHERE productid in(?)`,["1,2,3,4,5"] ,(error, results, fields)=> {...})
// results length is 1
```

The results are different？？？

Comment: `connection.query` is NOT MySQL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, in your first example, you have a list of numbers, but in your second, you have a single string. You can see the same results in the second if you used strings in the first like

```
SELECT * FROM shop_product WHERE productid in('1,2,3,4,5')
```

You want to use an array of numbers in your values, like the following:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM shop_product WHERE productid in(?)`,[[1,2,3,4,5]] ,(error, results, fields)=> {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

From a MySQL/MariaDB point of view:

```
id IN (1,2,3,4,5)  -- valid for integers
id IN ("1,2,3,4,5") -- typical mistake; that's one string value, not 5
name IN ("a","b","c","dd","eee") -- valid for strings
id IN ("1","2","3","4","5") -- ok for integers
```

Also, apostrophe (`'`) works in place of double-quote (`"`)

It is up to you to figure out whether `connection.query` will substitute things correctly.  If you add a tag for what interface is being used, you might get someone who can elaborate on `connection.query`.